# No "full service" Haskell org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, haskell-mode

I'm guessing that since Haskell's ghci is not a full-fledged REPL, you can't really use it for defining functions in orgmode source blocks, i.e.,

```
#+begin_src haskell 
doubleMe x = x + x 
#+end_src
```

isn't allowed in the ghci. But then

```
#+begin_src haskell 
let doubleMe x = x + x 
#+end_src
```

works, but

```
#+begin_src haskell
let doubleSmallNumber4 x = if x > 0
                            then x 
                             else x*2 
#+end_src
```

complains about parsing the `else`. I'm assuming Haskell and orgmode simply don't play well together -- at least when it comes to using orgmode source blocks . . . or am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be an indentation problem? Beware of tabs in haskell, use spaces for indentation.

Comment: Putting the if statement all on one line works, but multi-line is a no-go in ghci. orgmode simply isn't doing Haskell in the way it does C or Scheme et al.

Comment: You might need to add `:set +m` to `~/.ghc/ghci.conf` in order to enable multiline input. Or have you done so already?

Answer (score 10):

You need to enable multi-line commands support in GHCi. Put `:set +m` to GHCi config file or execute it directly in org-babel session as shown in the following code:

```
#+begin_src haskell

:set +m

let doubleSmallNumber4 x = if x > 0
                            then x 
                             else x*2 

doubleSmallNumber4 42

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for Haskell source blocks in org-mode is to use [emacs-jupyter](https://github.com/dzop/emacs-jupyter) with the [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) kernel.

Multi-line code blocks work as expected, e.g.

```
#+begin_src jupyter-haskell
  let doubleSmallNumber4 x = if x > 0
                              then x 
                               else x*2 

  doubleSmallNumber4 2
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2
```